# Issue with mysqli (I think) and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I posted on here a couple of days ago and was flagged as a duplicate. I have corrected (as far as I can tell) all of the mysql/mysqli inconsistencies in my code. As far as I can tell, this should work. But, all I'm getting is up to the first heading, and some basics from CSS (the background color and the border/container). It doesn't give an error in the browser and there are not any errors in /var/log/. I've even gone so far as to completely building an entirely new web server. When I posted the other day I was on Ubuntu 15.04 and I decided to move to CentOS 7. I've also upgrade to php v7. I have 2 other sites hosted on this vm and they are both working great - they are just wordpress sites. I've literally gone through every single line of code from every page and I cannot figure out the issue here.

Please do not ban me - if this is a duplicate somehow (even after spending hours searching for some indication of where the issue is - and I think that's the problem, I can't identify where it's not working exactly) please let me know how it's a duplicate. The last post I made changes but because it was flagged as a duplicate no one can see the update, and nothing gets resolved. I'm a full time sysadmin and wanna-be-web-dev sparingly on the side, just looking for help from people much more intelligent with this stuff than I am.

ANYWAY. I'm having the same issue on all the pages. Either I get the basics such as a heading and background with no actual data, or I just get background.

**phpfunctions.php** (this is referenced on all pages)

This is just a sample of what's in this, but they all follow the same format and this was working before I started adding pages and changed to mysqli (I've only added 2 functions, both of which were working, prior to all these changes)

```
<?php

    function db_connect() {

        static $connection;

        if(!isset($connection)) {

            $config = parse_ini_file('/info/config.ini'); 
            $connection = mysqli_connect($config['dbname'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'],'3306');

            }

        if($connection === false) {

            return mysqli_connect_error(); 

            }

        return $connection;
    }

    function close(){
        mysqli_close();
    }

    function make(){
        $qmake = mysqli_query( "SELECT VMakeID, VMake FROM vmake ORDER BY vmake");
        while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($qmake)){
            echo '<option value="' . $record['VMakeID'] . '">' . $record['VMake'] . '</option>';
        }
    }

?>
```

**index.php**
I think that if I can figure out why this page isn't working, then the rest will fall into place since this appears to be a widespread issue.

```
<head>

<title>Jeremy Cherokee</title>

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="css/justanerd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="files/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print"/>

<?php

    include_once 'php/phpfunctions.php';
    db_connect();

?>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <?php include ("layout/header.php"); ?>

        <?php include ("layout/banner.php"); ?>

        <div class="maininfo">
            <h2>
                My Garage
            </h2>
            <div class="current">

                <?php

                    $sql = "    SELECT  vehicles.VYear, 
                                        vmake.VMake, 
                                        vmodel.VModel, 
                                        vehicles.VTrim, 
                                        vehicles.VehicleID,
                                        vehicles.VThumbnail

                                FROM    vehicles 
                                        INNER JOIN mycars.vmake ON vehicles.VMakeID = vmake.VMakeID
                                        INNER JOIN mycars.vmodel ON vehicles.VModelID = vmodel.VModelID

                                WHERE vehicles.VCurrentlyOwn = '1'";

                    $result = mysqli_query($sql)or die(mysqli_error());

                    echo "<table>";
                    echo "  <tr>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Make</th>
                                <th>Model</th>
                                <th>Trim</th>
                                <th>".'<a href="newcar.php"><img src="images/addnew.png" width="33px" height="25px"></a>'."</th>
                                <th>".'<img src="images/redx.png" width="33px" height="25px">'."</th>
                            </tr>";

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                        $year   =   $row['VYear'];
                        $make   =   $row['VMake'];
                        $model  =   $row['VModel'];
                        $trim   =   $row['VTrim'];
                        $vid    =   $row['VehicleID'];
                        $pic    =   $row['VThumbnail'];

                        echo "  <tr>
                                    <td style='width: 50px;'>".$year."</td>
                                    <td style='width: 175px;'>".$make."</td>
                                    <td style='width: 200px;'>".$model."</td>
                                    <td style='width: 100px;'>".$trim."</td>
                                    <td style='width: 25px;'>".'<a href="mycarsprofile.php?id=' .$vid. '"><img src="images/document.png" width="33px" height="25px"></a>'."</td>
                                    <td style='width: 25px;'>".'<a href="soldvehicle.php?id=' .$vid. '"><img src="images/redx.png" width="33px" height="25px"></a>'."</td>
                                </tr>";

                    }

                    echo "</table>"

                ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php include ("layout/footer.php"); ?>

    <!-- end .container -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know that i'm prone to SQL injections and I'm sure there are some things I can tidy up. I'm going to work on that, but first I just want it to work now and I can improve later.

I've also tried several attempts at moving the db_connect stuff around. For example, instead of including phpfunctions I just went and put the connection information directly into the php page and it had no impact on the page - same exact issue.

The more complicated mysql_connect stuff came from [this link](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17) but I've tried simplifying it to what I know worked before which is this:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("mysql01", "mycaradmin", "secret") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 

    mysql_select_db("mycars") 
        or die(mysql_error()); 

?>
```

Obviously that was before I started adding things that didn't appear to work in mysql so when I added this directly into the index.php I changed the mysql to mysqli but when I did that it doesn't even give the header or the maininfo section anymore and only displays the background.

I apologize for the long winded question, but hopefully I provided enough information to get me going the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I created a test page based on the information from the php documentation for mysqli_connect and I have success.

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("mysql01", "jeremy", "secret", "mycars");

    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
        }

    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

I get the following:

```
Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great. Host information: mysql01 via TCP/IP
```

Comment: Your first parameter must be host  not dbname `mysqli_connect($config['dbname']` ..

Comment: Ok - I changed it to be: "$connection = mysqli_connect($config['dbhost'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname'],'3306');" but i'm still getting the same result

Comment: Removing the entire section dealing with the include_once made no impact on the results. This means it must be something with the setup of the VM ... i'm investigating

Comment: Know that some `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` functions are not a 'straight' transition by simply adding the "i". There are also some argument/parameter difference between the two. So, one example that you have: mysqli_query($sql) => mysqli_query(db_connect(), $sql) ... so make sure to check the relative `mysqli_*` function APIs at PHP.net

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be caused by the difference in syntax between mysql and mysqli commands. Once I found a good basis for the mysqli syntax, the pages started to work.